# Ubuntu won't suspend automatically any more

Tags: 12.04, power-management, suspend, screensaver, gnome-power-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity won't suspend on inactivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179248/unity-wont-suspend-on-inactivity)

In the last month or so, Ubuntu (12.04) has stopped sleeping automatically. I've gone to System Settings > Power, and verified (and toggled) "suspend on inactive for" to 5 minutes (for both battery and "when plugged in"), but the system stays awake.

I've also tried used code similar to

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 300
```

to set the timeout values. I've also verified these in dconf Editor. Previously, I could set this quite low to make my computer sleep quickly, but now it no longer works either.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but under old versions of Ubuntu, if I wanted my computer to never suspend (via the CLI), I would also have to set

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac false
```

At some point, this seemed to have been depreciated (and also gave me the error "No such key 'sleep-inactive-ac'"). I found that it it was enough to set sleep-inactive-ac-timeout to 0. This worked for a while, but at some point auto-suspend stopped working as stated above. Oddly enough, the sleep-inactive-ac key is still present when I look via dconf editor. However, when I click it, it says "no schema", and the summary, etc. fields are blank.

To test if the dconf power plugin was working, I tried playing around with other settings in the schema. Idle-dim-time and idle-dim-ac work as expected . However, setting sleep-display-ac to 5 seconds has no effect.

I'm also not sure if this is relevant, but I've uninstalled gnome-screensaver, and installed xscreensaver. I have tried killing xscreensaver and re-installing gnome-screensaver, but this did not help.

I've also had some trouble with DPMS. I'm not sure if this is related, but I'll put the information here, just in case. Using xscreensaver, I set Power Management to enabled, with standby and suspend timeouts to 10 minutes. I've verified these settings in ~/.xscreensaver and xset q. However, the screen blanks after about 30 seconds. If I turn off DPMS (either via xscreensaver GUI or modifying ~/.xscreensaver), it won't blank at all, so I know that DPMS *is* partially reading the xscreensaver settings.

-- edit
I've attempted more troubleshooting, by creating a new user account, then logging out of the main account and into the new account. I've tried modifying the timeouts via dconf, but get the same results as above (i.e. it doesn't work, nor does sleep-display-ac, but idle-dim-time and idle-dim-ac work). Also, the depreciated sleep-display-ac key is not visible, so I think that this is probably unrelated.

-- edit
I've since moved to gnome-shell instead of unity, and still have this problem, so I guess that it's something to do with gnome-power-manager.

Comment: If you are using a 32-bit OS, I think you have this [bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/989674?comments=all)

Comment: Also, see this [forum thread.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11926504)

Comment: Thanks for the comments jokerdino, but the problem is not so much waking from suspend, but more that I will not go _into_ suspend automatically. OTOH, I've actually just noticed the "Related" column on the right, and I've played around a bit with the suggestions from [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/180505/53508). This actually works somewhat, but I'll continue to tech and determine exactly what works and doesn't. I'll update the question (probably as a dupe) when I work out exactly what's happening. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Alright. Good luck with it. Hopefully you'll figure it out / the bug gets fixed. And sorry for overlooking the question. And, in case this question turns out to be a duplicate, feel free to flag it as such and we'll probably close it as a duplicate. Have a nice day otherwise.

Comment: Okay, I've flagged it as a dupe. I've now spent hours trying to isolate the (probable) bug, but it's quite frustrating. My system is now suspending properly, but after reverting all the settings, I cannot replicate the bug any more! Perhaps the toggle back and forth was enough, but it's annoying that I can't isolate it. Oh well. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I don't know if it's the same bug as in the other question, but I think it is a bug/regression from recently.  I've been experiencing odd suspend issues for the last day or two, so it might be a REALLY recent update

Comment: @aking1012: I noticed it about 2–3 months ago, so perhaps it's a different problem. (I upgrade my system daily.) Unfortunately I can't be more specific with what fixed it for me, so I can't really give more advice than what's in the other thread.